# Put significance asterisks in the horizontal middle of each bar in a barplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I wrote a class called `Chi2Independence`. With this class you can perform a Chi2 Test of Independence between two categorical variables. The class has also a method called `test_residuals` where the standardized residuals are tested for significance. Finally you can visualize the results using the method `plot`. Significant combinations of categories will be indicated by placing an asterisk above the respective bar. However in the current version the asterisks are not exactly in the middle of the bars but shifted slightly to the left. Here's a minimal example where a dummy data frame is created and then visualized using my plot function:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create a the dataframe
chi2_df = pd.DataFrame({'survived':[0,0,0,1,1,1],
                        'class':['First','Second','Third','First','Second','Third'],
                        'Frequency':[80,97,372,136,87,119],
                        'sig':[True,True,True,True,True,True]})

# plot results
def plot(df_freq,x_var,hue_var,title,dst_dir=None):

    stdres_sig_sorted = df_freq.sort_values(hue_var)['sig']

    barplot = sns.barplot(x=x_var, y='Frequency', hue=hue_var,data=df_freq)
    barplot.set_xticklabels(barplot.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45)
    barplot.get_xticklabels()
    barplot.set_title(title)

    for p,sig in zip(barplot.patches,stdres_sig_sorted):

        if sig == True:
            barplot.annotate('*', (p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2., p.get_height()),
                        ha='center', va='center', fontsize=11, color='gray', rotation=90, xytext=(0,10),
                        textcoords='offset points')

    plt.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 0.5), ncol=1)

    plt.tight_layout()

plot(df_freq=chi2_df,x_var='class',hue_var='survived',title='Class | Survived')
```

This is the output barplot:

[image: Barplot]

Does anyone know how to fix this problem so that the asterisks are exactly placed in the horizontal middle above each bar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would simply use `text` to place the asterisks with a `center` horizontal alignment. The vertical lines are plotted just to visually double check that the asterisks are in the center.

```
for p, sig in zip(barplot.patches,stdres_sig_sorted):
    if sig == True:
        barplot.text(p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2., p.get_height(), 
                     '*', ha='center')
        barplot.axvline(p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2., lw=0.5)
```

[image]